# PHP pages not showing in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I'm trying to deploy my first application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but I'm having some issues.

When I try to go to my php pages, a blank page is pulled up in the web browser. However all the html pages on my app are pulling fine (although they aren't styled). Anyone have any ideas why that is?

FYI: I'm not sure if I am connecting to my database instance on RDS correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pinpoint the issue via the logs. Go to your Elastic Beanstalk console and request the full logs. Once you got this zip you'll probably find an error in the `directory-hooks-executor.log` file (or any other file).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I figured it out! I didn't know that URL's past the top level domain were case-sensitive for Linux. I had one letter that wasn't the correct capitalization on my files.